# Intel Neural Compute Stick 2, Raspberry pi4, CNN network

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, intel

I have a code with CNN network on Raspberry, and now want to add Neural Compute Stick 2.
After installing Openvino, I am still confused about how to "import" Neural Compute Stick into my coding, and how it works.

Comment: You may want to start from this official video about NCS2 on the RasPi4: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PNmH_ugW6Zw

Comment: Basically you need to convert your model to an OpenVINO format in order to run inference on the VPU aka NCS2: https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/index.html